# Call to undefined function isLoggedIn()

Tags: php

I do not understand why the `isLoggedIn();` function isn't defined according to the error I am receiving. I have two pages one is a .php where functions are defined and a .phtml where I am having the issue. Below is the code for both.

```
public function isLoggedIn() {
 if(!session_id()) {
     return false;
 }
 else
 {
     return true;
 }
 }
```

Above is on the .php, which shows its function.

```
<?php
   $is_logged_in = isLoggedIn();
   if($is_logged_in) {
     echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
   }
   else {
     echo '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
   }
?>
```

Above is on the .phtml, which should work, as far as I am aware.

The very top of the .phtml document has

```
<?php require ('Models/SessionData.php');
```

Which is the name and location of the functions definition.

On the IDE there is no sign of anything being wrong.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `isLoggedIn()` is part of a class (hence the `public` keyword). You cannot simply call object methods on their own (unless they're `static`). You'll need to instantiate a new object of whatever type the class is.

Comment: Because it's not a function, it's a class method (as per the `public` keyword);

Comment: Although quite why checking `session_id()` constitutes checking if a user is logged in beats me...

Comment: Please realise if you cannot be bothered to give the complete story i.e. all the code, then you are not going to get any sort of useful answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

change it to

```
class logging{
public function isLoggedIn() {
     if(!session_id()) {
         return false;
     }
     else
     {
         return true;
     }
     }
}
```

and then change the other part to

```
$is_logged_in = new logging;
if($is_logged_in->isLoggedIn()) {
```

That should work

Comment: This really doesn't belong in a class of its own. Use the ternary operation as shown in my answer...

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in the comments, it looks like `isLoggedIn()` is part of a class (hence the public keyword). You cannot simply call object methods on their own (unless they're static). You'll need to instantiate a new object of whatever type the class is.

It seems that `isLoggedIn()` just checks `session_id()`, so you could easily extrapolate that into your code and simplify the whole thing. Your PHTML snippet could be rewritten using a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) as:

```
echo (session_id()) ? '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>' : '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
```

That having been said though, the method's probably in a class for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

remove the word `public`.

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    if (!session_id()) {
       return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

although you should probably follow the advice of others and look into classes

Comment: If `isLoggedIn()` is inside a class, removing the `public` keyword won't have any effect.

Comment: i see no class in the example given. removing the `public` keyword will make the script work procedurally.

Comment: He's including the class, with the function isLoggedIn, that's why just removing the public part won't fix anything, although it would work as long as the function is in the same file as the code calling the function.

Comment: he's using `require()` a script which is identical to `include()` except for the producing errors. This doesn't imply the existence of a class. Although i agree that isLoggedIn() probably did come from a class at some point, removing the word `public` in this instance will definitely work.

Comment: @adamS You can't have the `public` keyword outside of a class scope, so the method clearly _is_ in a class. Using `public` outside of a class will yield a parse error.

Comment: this is true which is why I suggested to simply remove the offending keyword instead of constructing a class around 1 function that calls 1 function. @BenM has makes a good point that this doesn't really belong in a class.

Answer (score 0):

`isLoggedIn()` is a `public` function meaning that you must use an object to access that function. (OOP)

To call fhe function, an object of `SessionData` must exist:

Example:

```
$session = new SessionData();
$is_logged_id = $session->isLoddedIn();
```

Check for the object in your included scripts, it could have been already instantiated (some global variable).